# HTML.textBoxFor(x=>x.Price, disabled = true) doesn't post the value to the controller post action!

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Asp .net MVC 3 application...
This is the View:

```
    Grupa: <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Grupa, Model.ListaGrupe) %> 
    Produsul: <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Produs, Model.ListaProduse) %> 
    Cantitate: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Cantitate, new { style = "width: 100px;" })%>
    Pret: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pret, new { style = "width: 100px;", disabled = true})%>
    TVA: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TVA, new { style = "width: 100px;", disabled = true })%>
    Valoare: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NoTVA, new { style = "width: 120px;", disabled = true})%>
    Valoare cu TVA: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Total, new { style = "width: 120px;", disabled = true})%>
```

I am using some JQuery to change Pret, TVA, NoTVA and Total based on the values in Grupa, Produs and Cantitate so I don't want the user to modify the values inside them. 
Probably disabled = true shoudn't be used. Then how can I make so the user can't modify the fields but the value to be posted to the controller's action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also make them readonly rather than disabling them. On the other note, I think @Chris solution is better, that way your modified data will be posted back.

Comment: I'm kind of new in the field of html /asp.net mvc . In this context, what would be the expression of using readonly?

Comment: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Total, new { style = "width: 120px;", @readonly = true})%>   I was using readonly without the @ and that's why I was searching for an alternative.... Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html.HiddenFor() and use a `<span>` or `<div>` instead. Their values will then be posted back.

Comment: @davvidd add the data between span/p/div tags e.g. `<p>@Model.TVA</p>` and add the hidden field too

Comment: what about if an advanced user will use JS to alter the Hidden field value ?

Comment: @TomerW check for valid values in the controller, no different from webforms but without the silly viewstate

Comment: @ChrisS. ofcourse, i didn't make my point clearly.
lets say you have a form the form is AlterJob and there is JobID=123 field which should be Readonly, i dont want anyone to be able to change it to JobID=234,  but should be passed by the form...
is there an easier way then to put another Encrypted field?
or a way to automate this Hashed values?

Comment: @TomerW I'd use a guid for the job id, and if you wanted better looking IDs then they can be used for the GET, and the hidden field contains the guid value. You can (and should imo) put other protection in to verify the person can update the job with the ID, check their roles etc.

Comment: Also readonly fields can be tampered with, as can hidden fields

Comment: @ChrisS. You are absolutly correct, i am implementing the Encryption mechanism, and will put the ID as GUID, for another small measure of security. thats a good idea

Comment: Funny MS didn't implement such mechanism to guard read only fields using encrypted value inside validation framework, i will do so and post it for anyone interested ...

Comment: @TomerW sounds interesting, drop a link in the comments when it's ready!

Comment: i wonder, is it enough to save in the Session all the relevant values, and then check that the returned value is equal?
seems like an ok solution, but i feel like it is missing something.

Comment: posted another answer with the VlidationAttribute i created....
plz comment feedback.
it isn't using encryption, but saves server side info instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what i did up to now,
i didn't succeed to make a good, easy to use, readonly protection using encryption,
but i did manage to do something that i think might just do.

how it works:

- When you use `LockObject(o)` an object, itterate the properties that have defined `ProtectedAttribute` defined for.
- add the locked value to a list, specially made for this field.
  ! the list is kept in the user session (on the server side)
- when the user submits the form, `IsValid` checks to see if the value is in the list of locked values.  if yes, then it is all ok.  otherwise, it must have been changed somehow.

! the number of values is not that big, and is temporary to the session, but if it is bothering someone, a simple `lockList.remove(node);` can easly be added when a value is validated.
Note: this can cause problem when the user uses Back buttons or Resubmit a form using Refresh.

tell me if you find any problems that this model does not take into account...
+ the Equalization is very naive, so it works only with value-types for time be.

---

Code:

Created an attribute named `ProtectedAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class ProtectedPropertyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static Dictionary<string, LinkedList<object>> savedValues;
    static ProtectedPropertyAttribute()
    {
        savedValues = (Dictionary<string, LinkedList<object>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ProtectedAttributeData"];
        if (savedValues != null) 
            return;
        savedValues = new Dictionary<string, LinkedList<object>>();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ProtectedAttributeData", savedValues);
    }

    public static void LockObject(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            LockProperty(obj, property);
        }
    }

    public static void LockProperty(object obj, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        ProtectedPropertyAttribute protectedAttribute =
            (ProtectedPropertyAttribute)
            property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ProtectedPropertyAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (protectedAttribute == null)
            return;
        if(protectedAttribute.Identifier == null)
            protectedAttribute.Identifier = property.Name;

        LinkedList<object> list;
        if (!savedValues.TryGetValue(protectedAttribute.Identifier, out list))
        {
            list = new LinkedList<object>();
            savedValues.Add(protectedAttribute.Identifier, list);
        }
        list.AddLast(property.GetValue(obj, null));
    }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public ProtectedPropertyAttribute()
    {
    }

    public ProtectedPropertyAttribute(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    public ProtectedPropertyAttribute(Func<string> errorMessageAccessor) : base(errorMessageAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        LinkedList<object> lockedValues;

        if (Identifier == null)
            Identifier = validationContext.DisplayName;

        if (!savedValues.TryGetValue(Identifier, out lockedValues))
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.MemberName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });

        bool found = false;
        LinkedListNode<object> node = lockedValues.First;
        while (node != null)
        {
            if(node.Value.Equals(value))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            node = node.Next;
        }

        if(!found)
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.MemberName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

place this attribute on any property of your model just as any other validation.

```
public class TestViewModel : Controller
{
    [ProtectedProperty("You changed me. you bitch!")]
    public string DontChangeMe { get; set; }

    public string ChangeMe { get; set; }
}
```

in the controller, after you are finished with the viewmodel object,
you call   `ProtectedAttribute.LockObject(myViewModel)`

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestViewModel vm = new TestViewModel {ChangeMe = "a1", DontChangeMe = "b1"};
        ProtectedPropertyAttribute.LockObject(vm);
        return View(vm);
    }


    public string Submit(TestViewModel vm)
    {
        string errMessage;
        return !validate(out errMessage) ? "you are a baaad, man." + errMessage : "you are o.k";
    }

    private bool validate(out string errormessage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            errormessage = null;
            return true;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> pair in ModelState)
        {
            sb.Append(pair.Key);
            sb.Append(" : <br/>");

            foreach (ModelError err in pair.Value.Errors)
            {
                sb.Append(" - ");
                sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage);
                sb.Append("<br/>");
            }

            sb.Append("<br/>");
        }
        errormessage = sb.ToString();
        return false;
    }
}
```