# ReadOnly(true) property's value not binded in Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, model-binding

One of my properties is marked with ReadOnly(true) attribute and in the model's Add view i'm assigning a default value to this property, DateTime.Now in my case.

The problem is that in the Add's POST action, the model arrived OK except of the ReadOnly(true) property, it's arrived 1/1/0001(it's DateTime).

What can I do to solve it? I do want to get the value.

Thanks

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395476/html-textboxforx-x-price-disabled-true-doesnt-post-the-value-to-the-contr will solve your problem.


  [1]:

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from "[OdeToCode.com](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)":

> ReadOnly metadata might be want you want to use if you never want to
>   bind the IsAdmin property. (Note: I remember ReadOnly not working in
>   MVC 2 or MVC 1, but it is working in 3 & 4 (beta)). public class User
>   {

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[ReadOnly(true)]
public bool IsAdmin { get; set; } }
```

Comment: This explains how to *avoid* model binding values, while also marking them as read-only. This is the opposite of what the question asks.